# React fetch api from Laravel Passport

Tags: reactjs, laravel, laravel-passport

I created a Rest Api with Laravel and Passport.
I can access from Postman without problem inserting Authorization > Bearer Token after launch php artisan passport:install.

Now I'm trying to access to Api with React+Axios, but I receive Request failed with status code 401.

```
const token = 'eyJ0eXA2d....'

const instance = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'https://exmample.com/api/',
    timeout: 1000,
    headers: { 
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token 
    }
});

const fetchLeads = async () => {
    const response = await axios
        instance.get('leads')
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log("Err: ", err);
        });
};

useEffect(() => {
    fetchLeads();
}, []);
```

[image]

I missing something from React or Laravel Passport require extra setting for connect with Axios?

routes -> api.php (Passport)

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'admin']], function () {
    Route::middleware('auth:api')->group(function(){
        Route::get('/leads', [LeadController::class, 'index'])->name('api.leads')->middleware('auth:api');
    });
});
```

Comment: You set instance but used axiosinstance?

Comment: I used axios instance in fetchLeads function.

Comment: But you called instance not axios instance

Comment: I changed the call like this: const response = await instance.get('/leads'), but always 401.

Comment: what is your laravel log?

Comment: can you share your route file?

Comment: @gguney updated my question with route file.

Comment: What is admin middleware ? can you remove it and try again ?

Comment: my laravel app is based on roles. But my api works with postman and axios in blade file. My problem is with react.

Comment: Did you increase the timeout?

Comment: From axios.create? yes done now. but is same 401.

Comment: Did you try https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2021/09/25/react-axios-interceptor-to-set-auth-header-for-api-requests-if-user-logged-in this interceptor method?

Comment: I was thinking.... maybe is because laravel run on  https://myexample.test and React app on http://localhost:3000/, something about cross origin request?

Comment: No haven't tried, I'll try to learn it and return here if resolve. thanks for help!

Comment: Just install laravel telescope for debugging and check how your headers/payload looks like. It helped me a lot while developing my API for a Vue JS front-end. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/telescope